# How to set CPU number and its cores when I create a Virtual Server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've used SoftLayer Java API to create Virtual Server and want to set CPU number and core number. I know hardware have have "processorCoreAmount" could be set core number, and here is part of my code:

```
Guest guest = new Guest();
guest.setHostname("host-" + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5).toLowerCase());
guest.setDomain(t.getDatacenter() + ".softlayer.com");
guest.setStartCpus(2);
guest.setMaxCpuUnits(4); 
**guest.setProcessorCoreAmount(4);** // no such a method.
```

My question:

1. How to set Processor Core Amount in Virtual Server?
2. Does MaxCpuUnits could be limit the Max CPU number or Max Core number of each CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a order you can oly can set the "StartCpus" property see: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

only the vales displayed in documentation can be set.

Also you can get all the avialable proccessor for order by calling the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions

Regards

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer, so we cannot set proccessor number (cores) when create Virtual instance, and only can use exist avialable proccessor or template?  our product interfact will give SoftLayer two properties when request compute instance: 
"ncpus": ["Numeric", "4"],  //Number of cpus
"ncores": ["Numeric", "8"], //Number of cores
How to pass ncores value to SoftLayer side? or maybe there have other ways to implement it?

Comment: That is not possible even using control portal I've never seen such thing, you can only select pre-set proccess, then you can customize the ram, disks, os and the other stuff that you can see in control portla when you order a server

Comment: Thanks, I saw there have 15 options in Processors selection,  do we need to verify user input CPU numbers based on these 15 options? I found input 3 CPU numbers also can provision the Virtual Server. And also, how indicate the Private Cores and what's the different between Private & non-Private cores?

Comment: well if you are planning to ask your customer for the CPU numbers in that case the answer is yes you need to make sure that those options are based in the options that the getCreateObjectOptions method return, otherwise you will get an error regarding that the process that you picked out does not exist or it is not available.  Regarding the Private and Public cores you will see that information in the description of the CPU. All the private CPUs have the prefix Private and to order them you just need to add the property dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag = true

Comment: You will notice that each item has a property called "template", that porperty tells you the parameters that you need to set in your order template to order that particular item.

Comment: Also I recomend you take a look to the softlayer blog http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog there are some articles that may interested you regarding to order VSI or CCI

Comment: Got it, very appreciated!!

Comment: Sorry, I have another question: do we need to set disk size when request VM? if yes, how to set disk size? I saw CreateObjectOptions has a blockdevice object, can we use this object to set/choose disk size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you have to use the blockdevice object the valid sizes for the disks is also displayed by the getcreateObjectOptions, please mark this answer as the correct regrads